# Runtime error creating map c++ visual studio compiler

Tags: c++

I'm doing the task from site https://www.codingame.com/ide/puzzle/mean-max. As I understood it uses VS compiler. I written the code below to solve the task.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

 struct point {
     int x, y;
 };

 struct tri {
     double d;
     int times;
     point coords;
 };

int main()
{
    // game loop
    while (1) {
        map<point, int> w;
        point coords;
        float mass;
        int friction;
        int throttle;
        vector<tri> a;

        int my_score;
        cin >> my_score; cin.ignore();
        int enemy_score_1;
        cin >> enemy_score_1; cin.ignore();
        int enemy_score_2;
        cin >> enemy_score_2; cin.ignore();
        int my_rage;
        cin >> my_rage; cin.ignore();
        int enemy_rage_1;
        cin >> enemy_rage_1; cin.ignore();
        int enemy_rage_2;
        cin >> enemy_rage_2; cin.ignore();
        int unit_count;
        cin >> unit_count; cin.ignore();
        for (int i = 0; i < unit_count; i++) {
            int unit_id;
            int unit_type;
            int player;
            float mass;
            int radius;
            int x;
            int y;
            int vx;
            int vy;
            int extra;
            int extra_2;
            cin >> unit_id >> unit_type >> player >> mass >> radius >> x >> y >> vx >> vy >> extra >> extra_2; cin.ignore();
            if (unit_type == 4) {
                if (!w.count({x, y}))
                    w[{x,y}] = 0;
                w[{x,y}]++;
            }
            if (unit_id == 0) {
                coords = {x, y};
            }
        }

        for (auto p : w) {
            a.push_back(tri {sqrt(pow(coords.x - p.first.x, 2) + pow(coords.y - p.first.y, 2)),
            p.second, p.first});
        }

        // sort(a.begin(), a.end(), [&](tri& t1, tri& t2) {
        //     return t1.d > (throttle / mass) && t2.d <= (throttle / mass);
        // });

        for (auto p : a) {
            cerr << p.d << ' ';
        }

        int l = -1, r = 300;
        while (l + 1 < r) {
            int m = (l + r) >> 1;
            if (m / mass >= a[0].d) {
                r = m;
            } else {
                l = m;
            }
        }
        throttle = r;

        // Write an action using cout. DON'T FORGET THE "<< endl"
        // To debug: cerr << "Debug messages..." << endl;

        cout << a[0].coords.x << ' ' << a[0].coords.y << ' ' << throttle <<  endl;
        cout << "wait" << endl;
        cout << "WAIT" << endl;
    }
}
```

It throws an runtime error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/string:48,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/iostream:39,
                 from /tmp/Answer.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_function.h: In instantiation of ‘constexpr bool std::less<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) const [with _Tp = point]’:
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_map.h:519:32:   required from ‘std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type&&) [with _Key = point; _Tp = int; _Compare = std::less<point>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const point, int> >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = int; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = point]’
/tmp/Answer.cpp:71:28:   required from her
...
_Tp> std::operator<(const _Up&, const std::optional<_Tp>&)’
 1173 |     operator<(const _Up& __lhs, const optional<_Tp>& __rhs)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/optional:1173:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/string:48,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/iostream:39,
                 from /tmp/Answer.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_function.h:386:20: note:   ‘const point’ is not derived from ‘const std::optional<_Tp>’
  386 |       { return __x < __y; }
      |                ~~~~^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/map:61,
                 from /tmp/Answer.cpp:5:
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_map.h:1501:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Allocator>&, const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Allocator>&)’
 1501 |     operator<(const map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>& __x,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_map.h:1501:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/string:48,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/iostream:39,
                 from /tmp/Answer.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_function.h:386:20: note:   ‘const point’ is not derived from ‘const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Allocator>’
  386 |       { return __x < __y; }
      |                ~~~~^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/map:62,
                 from /tmp/Answer.cpp:5:
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_multimap.h:1166:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Allocator>&, const std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Allocator>&)’
 1166 |     operator<(const multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>& __x,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_multimap.h:1166:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/string:48,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/iostream:39,
                 from /tmp/Answer.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_function.h:386:20: note:   ‘const point’ is not derived from ‘const std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Allocator>’
  386 |       { return __x < __y; }
```

What do I need to fix? It will work at AppleClang, which I used most. And I had not experience with VS compiler before.

Comment: That is not a runtime error, it's a compiler error. Very different things

Comment: This looks like GCC output, not MSVC. This shouldn't work on any compiler: using a class as a key for `std::map` requires it to have `operator<`, or a custom comparator to be specified as map's third template argument.

Comment: This is a compile timer error and not a very helpful one.  It's saying that you need an `operator<` for `struct point`.

Comment: I added `operator<` overload for `point`, but it didn't help.

Comment: I'm sorry, I added it wrong the first time. It has helped!

Comment: @Aliensis *It will work at AppleClang* -- [It shouldn't work there either](https://godbolt.org/z/h565h3WW7).  A `std::map` requires a key that can be ordered, and `point` is not orderable until `operator <` is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

std:: map requires operator< for Key type. You should consider [std::unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).